# How to put different content for each cards

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui album template for my react app
I want to put different image and different text for each cards for this when I remove this array it create the problems in responsiveness of the cards

I tried to put separte grid for each cards but thats some how solve the issue but that responsiveness of the template does not remain same

here is my demo code
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pz8df

Comment: Hi Blawal, try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're updating the right `cards` array. Use an array of objects as well, where each object has a key for an image-link and one for the description. In the `.map()` we'll use these values to render the content. Here's a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3v44c

The responsiveness will work like expected.

Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CameraIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PhotoCamera";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

function MadeWithLove() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {"Built with love by the "}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Material-UI
      </Link>
      {" team."}
    </Typography>
  );
}
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  heroContent: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 6)
  },
  heroButtons: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(4)
  },
  cardGrid: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(8)
  },
  card: {
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  cardMedia: {
    paddingTop: "56.25%" // 16:9
  },
  cardContent: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: theme.spacing(6)
  }
}));

const cards = [
  {
    img:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564135624576-c5c88640f235?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3300&q=80",
    desc: "Campsite"
  },
  {
    img:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564198879220-63f2734f7cec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2072&q=80",
    desc: "Space"
  }
];

export default function Album() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="relative">
        <Toolbar>
          <CameraIcon className={classes.icon} />
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
            Album layout
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <main>
        {/* Hero unit */}
        <div className={classes.heroContent}>
          <Container maxWidth="sm">
            <Typography
              component="h1"
              variant="h2"
              align="center"
              color="textPrimary"
              gutterBottom
            >
              Album layout
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="h5"
              align="center"
              color="textSecondary"
              paragraph
            >
              Something short and leading about the collection below—its
              contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too
              short so folks don&apos;t simply skip over it entirely.
            </Typography>
            <div className={classes.heroButtons}>
              <Grid container spacing={2} justify="center">
                <Grid item>
                  <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                    Main call to action
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">
                    Secondary action
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          </Container>
        </div>
        <Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="md">
          {/* End hero unit */}
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            {cards.map(card => (
              <Grid item key={card} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                  <CardMedia
                    className={classes.cardMedia}
                    image={card.img}
                    title="Image title"
                  />
                  <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                      Heading
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography>{card.desc}</Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary">
                      View
                    </Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary">
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </main>
      {/* Footer */}
      <footer className={classes.footer}>
        <Typography variant="h6" align="center" gutterBottom>
          Footer
        </Typography>
        <Typography
          variant="subtitle1"
          align="center"
          color="textSecondary"
          component="p"
        >
          Something here to give the footer a purpose!
        </Typography>
        <MadeWithLove />
      </footer>
      {/* End footer */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you so very much it works
i tried i can able to edit it as per requirments
intially i was rendering the array out and coming up with new grid every time which eventually causing page responsiveness
cheer !!

Comment: That is awesome! I'm glad this was helpful to you. Have a good one :) @Bilawal